match OptionMenu and Button width (and resizable images in expandable containers)
I have an OptionMenu and a Button in adjacent rows of the same column of a grid. I don't want the grid to manage the size of these widgets, because it can make the widgets much too wide. Instead, I would like for the OptionMenu and Button to be a fixed size - the maximum of the Button width, the OptionMenu width, and the widths of all menu entries. But I'm having trouble with this.
The widths and heights of the OptionMenu and Button are initially 1, so I must first bind <Configure> to let the grid geometry manager inform me of the desired sizes. To prevent an infinite loop, I immediately unbind the event in the handler.
I can then calculate the width of all the widgets in either pixels or text units. If I enforce the maximum width in the handler, I find that the OptionMenu "handle" adds a bit of width, so that the Button and OptionMenu widths are mismatched.
This forces me to nest the OptionMenu and Button widgets within frames of their own (which in turn are within the grid). Then I pack the OptionMenu and Button to expand, but disable pack propagation on the frame. The idea is to set the width of the frame, and have the nested widgets expand to fill.
Unfortunately the grid geometry manager informs my handler that the OptionMenu and Button now request 1x1 pixels of space, since pack propagation is disabled.
Next I started from scratch. Where the OptionMenu and Button would be I placed a Frame with a rowspan of 2; the frame's contents also managed by a (nested) grid geometry manager. The frame is sticky="w"; it would shrink to fit its contents. The contents are sticky="ew"; they would fill to a uniform size.
This works well, except that where text across columns of a single row would share a baseline, the nested grid geometry manager does not share baselines with the parent grid geometry manager. For example, the label text in the first column no longer shares a baseline with the OptionMenu text in the second column. Instead the baseline of the label text in the first column is now aligned with the bottom of the OptionMenu.
How can I fix this?
For example, here I've moved the "Cell (0,0)" label into the inner grid. This allows me keep the text aligned, but I lose the ability to center the nested columns within the outer columns.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.scrolledtext

import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk


class App:
    options = ["short", "really really really really long"]
    unselected = "<select item>"

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        title = parent.winfo_toplevel().title()
        font = tk.font.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")

        # Create a frame for the entire window
        frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Set the title label from the window title
        title_label = tk.Label(frame, text=title, font=font)
        title_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Load the logos
        logo1_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (0,255,0))
        logo2_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (255,0,0))

        logo1_label = tk.Label(frame, borderwidth=0)
        logo2_label = tk.Label(frame, borderwidth=0)

        # TODO:
        # I'm seeing slow-motion resize on large resizes. I believe that
        # multiple resizes are being queued, but I can't cancel that queue. I
        # need to make this callback schedule a cancellable callback that then
        # resizes.
        logo1_label.bind\
            ( "<Configure>"
            , lambda e, i=logo1_image, w=logo1_label: self.resizeimage(e, i, w)
            )
        logo2_label.bind\
            ( "<Configure>"
            , lambda e, i=logo2_image, w=logo2_label: self.resizeimage(e, i, w)
            )

        logo1_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        logo2_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        # Create a frame for interactive elements
        #input_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
        input_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")
        input_frame.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        input_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="column")
        input_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="column")

        # Label for cell (0,0)
        c00_label = tk.Label\
            (input_frame, font=font, text="cell (0,0)")
        c00_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        # Create the OptionMenu
        options_var = tk.StringVar()
        options_var.set(self.unselected)

        options = tk.OptionMenu(input_frame, options_var, *self.options)
        options.configure(font=font)
        options["menu"].configure(font=font)
        options.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        # Create the Button
        button = tk.Button\
            ( input_frame
            , font=font, text="implement option"
            )
        button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0), sticky="ew")

        # Create the labels for the 3rd row
        c30_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (3,0)")
        c30_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        c31_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (3,1)")
        c31_label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        text = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText\
            (frame, state=tk.DISABLED, font=font)
        text.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=100)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=4)

    @staticmethod
    def resizeimage(event, image, widget):
        image = image.copy()
        image.thumbnail\
            ( (event.width, event.height)
            , resample=PIL.Image.Resampling.BILINEAR
            , reducing_gap=None
            )
        image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        widget.config(image=image)
        # Images are not referenced by tkinter
        widget.image = image
        #widget.unbind("<Configure>")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Helpful Title")

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Edit: Here is a mostly-working version of the callback variant with frames described above. First you pack into the frame with propagation enabled. In the callback explicitly set the height to the current height, and the width to the maximum width of all the contained widgets, then disable callback propagation.
Unfortunately this version suffers two problems:

Measuring the OptionMenu labels is faulty and thus the buttons are sized too small to fit the really long menu entry.
Resizing the images triggers a callback storm; I don't know why!

How do I fix these problems?
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.scrolledtext

import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk


class App:
    options = ["short", "really really really really really long"]
    unselected = "<select item>"

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        title = parent.winfo_toplevel().title()
        font = tk.font.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")

        # Create a frame for the entire window
        frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Set the title label from the window title
        title_label = tk.Label(frame, text=title, font=font)
        title_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Load the logos
        logo1_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (0,255,0))
        logo2_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (255,0,0))

        logo1_label = tk.Label(frame, bg="orange", borderwidth=0)
        logo2_label = tk.Label(frame, bg="blue", borderwidth=0)

        logo1_label.resize_count = 0
        logo2_label.resize_count = 0
        logo1_label.resize_id = None
        logo2_label.resize_id = None
        print("logo1_label: ", logo1_label)
        print("logo2_label: ", logo2_label)

        # TODO:
        # I'm seeing slow-motion resize on large resizes. I believe that
        # multiple resizes are being queued, but I can't cancel the queue. I
        # need to make this callback schedule a cancellable callback that then
        # resizes.
        logo1_label.bind\
            ("<Configure>", lambda e, i=logo1_image: self.onconfigure_image(e, i))
        logo2_label.bind\
            ("<Configure>", lambda e, i=logo2_image: self.onconfigure_image(e, i))

        logo1_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
        logo2_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Label for cell (2,0)
        c00_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (2,0)")
        c00_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        # Create the OptionMenu
        options_var = tk.StringVar()
        options_var.set(self.unselected)

        options_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")

        options = tk.OptionMenu(options_frame, options_var, *self.options)
        options.configure(font=font)
        options["menu"].configure(font=font)

        options.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        options_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create the Button
        button_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")

        button = tk.Button\
            (button_frame, font=font, text="implement option")
        button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        button_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0))

        button.bind("<Configure>", self.onconfigure_button)

        # not sure why I can't get the font from the widget, ie:
        # font = tk.font.nametofont(self.options.cget("font"))
        # *** _tkinter.TclError: named font font1 does not already exist
        self.font = font
        self.options_frame = options_frame
        self.button_frame = button_frame
        self.options = options
        self.button = button

        # Create the labels for the 4th row
        c30_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (4,0)")
        c30_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        c31_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (4,1)")
        c31_label.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        text = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText\
            (frame, state=tk.DISABLED, font=font)
        text.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=100, uniform="column")
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100, uniform="column")
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=4)

    def onconfigure_button(self, event):
        menu = self.options["menu"]
        maxw = self.font.measure(self.unselected)
        print(maxw)
        for i in range(menu.index("end") + 1):
            label = menu.entrycget(i, "label")
            width = self.font.measure(label)
            maxw = max(maxw, width)
            print(label, width)
            #print(label, label.winfo_width())
        print("button width: ", self.button.winfo_width())
        maxw = max(maxw, self.button.winfo_width())
        print(maxw)
        # Wrapping both widgets in frames allowed us to sidestep the padding
        # added by the OptionMenu "handle". So while the widgets are now the
        # same size, the "handle" width is not accounted for in the width
        # calculations and may overlap with wide menu entries!
        #
        # I need a way to get the width of the menu "handle".
        self.options_frame.config(width=maxw)
        self.button_frame.config(width=maxw)
        self.options_frame.config(height=self.options_frame.winfo_height())
        self.button_frame.config(height=self.button_frame.winfo_height())
        self.options_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.button_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        event.widget.unbind("<Configure>")
        return

    # Question
    # When I maximize the window, four <Configure> events are generated, and I
    # see the images scaled-up in a slow-motion animation. I try to cancel or
    # skip older events, but each new <Configure> waits till after the resize
    # is complete... This suggests that the resize then affects the widget
    # size, leading the callback to be called in a loop... but the showsize()
    # callback shows that resizing the image does not change the widget size.
    #
    # Changing the resize to not preserve aspect ratio makes the problem much
    # worse. Clearly the change in height is forcing the geometry manager to
    # re-evaluate the layout. How do I prevent this?
    def onconfigure_image(self, event, image):
        print()
        widget = event.widget
        print("onconfigure for: ", widget)
        #if widget.resize_i is not None:
        #    print("cancelling previous resize: ", widget.resize_id)
        #    widget.after_cancel(widget.resize_id)
        #widget.resize_id = widget.after_idle(self.resize_image, event, image)
        widget.resize_id = widget.after(1, self.resize_image, event, image)
        widget.resize_count += 1
        print("scheduling resize with id: ", widget.resize_id)

    def showsize(self, widget):
        print()
        print("showsize for: ", widget)
        print("widget size: ", widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height())

    def resize_image(self, event, image):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.resize_count -= 1
        print()
        if widget.resize_count > 0:
            print(f"{widget.resize_count} events remaining, skipping resize")
            return
        print("widget size: ", widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height())
        print("resize_image for: ", widget)
        print("resize id, resize count: ", (widget.resize_id, widget.resize_count))
        widget.resize_id = None
        #image = image.copy()
        #image.thumbnail\
        image = image.resize\
            ( (event.width, event.height)
            , resample=PIL.Image.Resampling.BILINEAR
            , reducing_gap=None
            )
        image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        widget.config(image=image)
        # Images are not referenced by tkinter
        widget.image = image
        #widget.unbind("<Configure>")
        widget.after(1, self.showsize, widget)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Helpful Title")

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Edit: This version fixes the first problem (and removes a callback by using the req version of winfo_width(), etc) but I'm still dealing with the second point, the callback storm.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.scrolledtext

import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk


class App:
    options = ["short", "really really really long"]
    unselected = "<select item>"

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        title = parent.winfo_toplevel().title()
        font = tk.font.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")

        # Create a frame for the entire window
        frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Set the title label from the window title
        title_label = tk.Label(frame, text=title, font=font)
        title_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Load the logos
        logo1_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (0,255,0))
        logo2_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (255,0,0))

        logo1_label = tk.Label(frame, bg="orange", borderwidth=0, pady=0)
        logo2_label = tk.Label(frame, bg="blue", borderwidth=0, pady=0)

        logo1_label.resize_count = 0
        logo2_label.resize_count = 0
        logo1_label.resize_id = None
        logo2_label.resize_id = None
        print("logo1_label: ", logo1_label)
        print("logo2_label: ", logo2_label)

        # TODO:
        # I'm seeing slow-motion resize on large resizes. I believe that
        # multiple resizes are being queued, but I can't cancel the queue. I
        # need to make this callback schedule a cancellable callback that then
        # resizes.
        logo1_label.bind\
            ("<Configure>", lambda e, i=logo1_image: self.onconfigure_image(e, i))
        logo2_label.bind\
            ("<Configure>", lambda e, i=logo2_image: self.onconfigure_image(e, i))

        logo1_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
        logo2_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Label for cell (2,0)
        c00_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (2,0)")
        c00_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        # Create the OptionMenu
        options_var = tk.StringVar()
        options_var.set(self.unselected)

        options_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")

        options = tk.OptionMenu(options_frame, options_var, *self.options)
        options.configure(font=font, anchor="c")
        options["menu"].configure(font=font)

        options.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        options_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create the Button
        button_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")

        button = tk.Button\
            (button_frame, font=font, text="implement option", anchor="c")
        button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        button_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0))

        # not sure why I can't get the font from the widget, ie:
        # font = tk.font.nametofont(self.options.cget("font"))
        # *** _tkinter.TclError: named font font1 does not already exist
        self.font = font
        self.options_frame = options_frame
        self.button_frame = button_frame
        self.options = options
        self.button = button

        #parent.bind("<Configure>", self.onconfigure_button)
        self.onconfigure_button(None)

        # Create the labels for the 4th row
        c30_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (4,0)")
        c30_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        c31_label = tk.Label\
            (frame, font=font, text="cell (4,1)")
        c31_label.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        text = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText\
            (frame, state=tk.DISABLED, font=font)
        text.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=100, uniform="column")
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100, uniform="column")
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=0)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=4)

    def onconfigure_button(self, event):
        menu = self.options["menu"]
        maxw = self.font.measure(self.unselected)
        for i in range(menu.index("end") + 1):
            label = menu.entrycget(i, "label")
            width = self.font.measure(label)
            maxw = max(maxw, width)
        maxw = maxw / self.font.measure("0")
        maxw = math.ceil(maxw)

        # Allow the widget to request its optimal width.
        self.options.configure(width=maxw)

        maxw = max(self.button.winfo_reqwidth(), self.options.winfo_reqwidth())

        self.options_frame.config(width=maxw)
        self.button_frame.config(width=maxw)

        #print()
        #print("button frame act height: ", self.button_frame.winfo_height())
        #print("option frame act height: ", self.options_frame.winfo_height())
        #print("button frame req height: ", self.button_frame.winfo_reqheight())
        #print("option frame req height: ", self.options_frame.winfo_reqheight())

        #print("button act height: ", self.button.winfo_height())
        #print("option act height: ", self.options.winfo_height())
        #print("button req height: ", self.button.winfo_reqheight())
        #print("option req height: ", self.options.winfo_reqheight())

        self.options_frame.config(height=self.options.winfo_reqheight())
        self.button_frame.config(height=self.button.winfo_reqheight())
        self.options_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.button_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        #event.widget.unbind("<Configure>")

    # Question
    # When I maximize the window, four <Configure> events are generated, and I
    # see the images scaled-up in a slow-motion animation. I try to cancel or
    # skip older events, but each new <Configure> waits till after the resize
    # is complete... This suggests that the resize then affects the widget
    # size, leading the callback to be called in a loop... but the showsize()
    # callback shows that resizing the image does not change the widget size.
    #
    # Changing the resize to not preserve aspect ratio makes the problem much
    # worse. Clearly the change in height is forcing the geometry manager to
    # re-evaluate the layout. How do I prevent this?
    def onconfigure_image(self, event, image):
        print()
        widget = event.widget
        print("onconfigure for: ", widget)
        #if widget.resize_i is not None:
        #    print("cancelling previous resize: ", widget.resize_id)
        #    widget.after_cancel(widget.resize_id)
        #widget.resize_id = widget.after_idle(self.resize_image, event, image)
        widget.resize_id = widget.after(1, self.resize_image, event, image)
        widget.resize_count += 1
        print("scheduling resize with id: ", widget.resize_id)

    def showsize(self, widget):
        print()
        print("showsize for: ", widget)
        print("widget size: ", widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height())

    def resize_image(self, event, image):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.resize_count -= 1
        print()
        if widget.resize_count > 0:
            print(f"{widget.resize_count} events remaining, skipping resize")
            return
        print("widget size: ", widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height())
        print("resize_image for: ", widget)
        print("resize id, resize count: ", (widget.resize_id, widget.resize_count))
        widget.resize_id = None
        #image = image.copy()
        #image.thumbnail\
        image = image.resize\
            ( (event.width, event.height)
            , resample=PIL.Image.Resampling.BILINEAR
            , reducing_gap=None
            )
        image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        widget.config(image=image)
        # Images are not referenced by tkinter
        widget.image = image
        #widget.unbind("<Configure>")
        widget.after(1, self.showsize, widget)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Helpful Title")

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Edit: I assumed the geometry grid manager would keep a strict ratio between rows as per the defined weights. So given weights 1:4, a window resize would preserve a 1:4 ratio between the rows. However the geometry manager also considers the size requests of its children. If a window is resized to be larger and a child widget requests use of the new space, then the geometry manager will increase the weight of that child, triggering a new resize event. This happens up to a limit, at which the child can consume no further space. This effect even occurs between different (possibly nonadjacent) grid managers that share space.
Examining the events I could find no difference between window-resize events and grid-resize events. TKinter does not appear to tag the event source, so it isn't possible to simply filter out grid-resize events. I could also find no method of preventing child size requests from triggering grid-resize events. I though that disabling propagation might work, but no...
The only solution is to then bind the child resize to events originating further up the hierarchy, such as the root window, which will implicitly filter grid-resize events. This does unfortunately leave a gap as the grid manager then allocates more space for the child, so it is probably better to move affected children to another manager. It is possible to simulate grid-sizing through some non-linear ratio between the window size and the image size.
Edit: What I wrote applies not just to grid but to any geometry manager that expands into additional available space, such as pack with expand=True.

That said, instead of splitting up my existing grid I decided to try to set that row's weight to zero (disable expansion) and manually resize the cells upon changes to the outer frame... but that's a good way to crash tkinter:
def frame_configure_resize_grid_cell(self, event, image, widget):
    gridframe = event.widget
    if not gridframe.height:
        gridframe.height = event.height
        return
    print("frame old height, frame new height", gridframe.height, event.height)
    aspect = event.height / gridframe.height
    gridframe.height = event.height
    old_height = widget.winfo_height()
    #_,_,_,old_height = frame.grid_bbox(1,0)
    new_height = round(old_height * aspect)
    print("old height, aspect, new height: ", old_height, aspect, new_height)
    widget.config(height=new_height)


It's going to be hard to answer this without a concrete example. Layouts are  highly dependent on everything in a layout. For example, are these buttons together? Is one at the top of the uI and the other below? Are there widgets in-between? For me, the simplest way to get two widgets to be the same width is with grid, but it can sometimes be done with place, or by pack with the widgets in a frame. It all really depends on what else you have in the window.

Here is working variant. The trick is to place the images into a parent which will not expand, and when the window is scaled, manage the size of that parent yourself like any other geometry manager. Note that changing the image size can change the entire window size if the initial image size is not the desired initial size.
import math

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.scrolledtext

import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk


class App:
    options = ["short", "really really really long"]
    unselected = "<select item>"

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        title = parent.winfo_toplevel().title()
        font = tk.font.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")

        # Create a frame for the entire window
        frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Set the title label from the window title
        title_label = tk.Label(frame, text=title, font=font)
        title_label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create a frame for the logos
        logo_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
        logo_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False)

        # Load the logos
        logo1_image = self.load_image(path1, (200,200))
        logo2_image = self.load_image(path2, (200,200))

        logo1_label = tk.Label(logo_frame, borderwidth=0, bg="orange")
        logo2_label = tk.Label(logo_frame, borderwidth=0, bg="blue")

        self.config_image(logo1_label, logo1_image, (100,100))
        self.config_image(logo2_label, logo2_image, (100,100))

        logo1_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        logo2_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        image_widgets = [logo1_label, logo2_label]

        frame.size = None
        frame.resize_count = 0
        frame.bind\
            ("<Configure>", lambda e, w=image_widgets: self.resize_images(e, w))

        # Create a frame for the input
        input_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
        input_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Label for cell (2,0)
        c00_label = tk.Label\
            (input_frame, font=font, text="cell (0,0)")
        c00_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        # Create the OptionMenu
        options_var = tk.StringVar()
        options_var.set(self.unselected)

        options_frame = tk.Frame(input_frame, bg="red")

        options = tk.OptionMenu(options_frame, options_var, *self.options)
        options.configure(font=font, anchor="c")
        options["menu"].configure(font=font)

        options.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        options_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create the Button
        button_frame = tk.Frame(input_frame, bg="red")

        button = tk.Button\
            (button_frame, font=font, text="implement option", anchor="c")
        button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        button_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0))

        # not sure why I can't get the font from the widget, ie:
        # font = tk.font.nametofont(self.options.cget("font"))
        # *** _tkinter.TclError: named font font1 does not already exist
        width = self.equalwidths_fit(font, options, options_var, button)

        # Create the labels for the 4th row
        c20_label = tk.Label\
            (input_frame, font=font, text="cell (2,0)")
        c20_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        c21_label = tk.Label\
            (input_frame, font=font, text="cell (2,1)")
        c21_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        text = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText\
            (input_frame, state=tk.DISABLED, font=font)
        text.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        input_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=width, uniform="column")
        input_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=width, uniform="column")
        input_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        input_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        input_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        input_frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

    @staticmethod
    def load_image(path, size):
        image = PIL.Image.open(str(path))
        image.thumbnail(size, PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
        return image

    @staticmethod
    def config_image(widget, image, minimums):
        photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize(minimums))
        widget.image_original = image
        widget.image_minimums = minimums
        widget.photo = photo
        widget.config(image=photo)

    # Turns out to be unnecessary, and feels like it adds a slight latency.
    def queue_resizes(self, event, image_widgets):
        event.widget.after(1, self.resize_images, event, image_widgets)
        event.widget.resize_count += 1
        print("queueing resize: ", event.widget.resize_count)

    @staticmethod
    def resize_images(event, image_widgets):
        #event.widget.resize_count -= 1
        #print("events remaining: ", event.widget.resize_count)
        #if event.widget.resize_count > 0:
        #    print("addtional events remaining, skipping resize")
        #    return
        if event.widget.size is None:
            event.widget.size = (event.width, event.height)
        for widget in image_widgets:
            minw, minh = widget.image_minimums
            _, baseh = event.widget.size
            s = max(0, event.height - baseh)
            # Modify the scale factor here from the available space `s`:
            h = minh + s // 1.75
            w = max(minw, event.width // 2)

            image = widget.image_original
            iw, ih = image.width, image.height
            
            if iw*h > ih*w:
                # image is wider, match image and widget widths
                iw2 = w
                ih2 = w*ih//iw
            else:
                # widget is equal or wider, match image and widget heights
                ih2 = h
                iw2 = iw*h//ih

            d = (int(iw2), int(ih2))
            image = image.resize\
                (d, resample=PIL.Image.Resampling.BICUBIC, reducing_gap=3)
            photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            widget.photo = photo
            widget.config(image=photo)

    @staticmethod
    def equalwidths_fit(font, option, optvar, button):
        menu = option["menu"]
        maxw = font.measure(optvar.get())
        for i in range(menu.index("end") + 1):
            label = menu.entrycget(i, "label")
            width = font.measure(label)
            maxw = max(maxw, width)
        maxw = maxw / font.measure("0")
        maxw = math.ceil(maxw)

        # Allow the widget to request its optimal width.
        option.configure(width=maxw)

        maxw = max(button.winfo_reqwidth(), option.winfo_reqwidth())

        option_parent = option.master
        button_parent = button.master

        option_parent.config(width=maxw)
        button_parent.config(width=maxw)

        option_parent.config(height=option.winfo_reqheight())
        button_parent.config(height=button.winfo_reqheight())
        option_parent.pack_propagate(False)
        button_parent.pack_propagate(False)

        return maxw


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Helpful Title")

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I reached the maximum question size and so had to post this edit as a question instead. Luckily, it solves all my problems.

line 32, in init
logo1_image = self.load_image(path1, (200,200))
NameError: name 'path1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'math'?

No that's a placeholder for an image which I did not provide, but instead you could use PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200,200), (0,255,0)) or some such, though it is harder check correctness with a uniformly-colored image.

Sorry, my mistaken. logo1_image = self.load_image('p2.png', (200,200)). It is working now.
